# Проблема с записью в базу даных из парсера

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Задача: спарсить информацию с сайта и сохранить ее в нашу базу.

Нужную мне информацию я получаю и вывожу на экран, все как и нужно.
Но возникла проблема с записью информации в базу, а именно **с записью русских символов** .

В php файле парсера прописал:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1251');
mb_internal_encoding('Windows-1251'); 
mb_http_output('Windows-1251'); 
mb_http_input('Windows-1251');
```

Парсер работает на *simple_html_dom.php*

Сам код:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.favorit-auto.ru/producers/?page=1'); 
$a_links = $html->find('#producers_content .vendors li a');

foreach ($a_links as & $value) {

  $html2 = file_get_html('http://www.favorit-auto.ru'.$value->href.''); 
  $a_links2 = $html2->find('.vendor_text');


  $prod = $value->plaintext = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/', '', $value->plaintext);
  $prod1 = substr($prod, 0, -1);
  $url = translit($prod1);
  $opis = $a_links2[0]->plaintext;

  /* Добавляем производителя */
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `producers` (`url`, `name`, `content`) values('$url', '$prod1', '$opis')");

}
```

Что в итоге происходит: Запись в базу идет, но если получаем русский текст - в базу его не записывает, а на экран русский текст выводиться хорошо.

Параметр **Сравнение** для текстового поля, в базе стоит **utf8_general_ci**.
Пробовал установить `cp1250_bin` - теперь выходит что текст в базу записывается только англ. символы, а русские пишет как "*??? ??? ??????????? ??*"

Как мне решить эту проблему? Как подобрать нужную кодировку? 
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: почему вы используете Windows-1251? Это вызвано необходимостью? Донор старый?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin я пробовал использовать UTF-8 - в итоге на экран выводило непонятные символы